# ELIFECYCLE 1 Error when pushing to Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, git-push

My first question here. Doing a project in React.JS. I been looking around for the same issue that I have but not been able to find a solution that fit's mine.

After committing my project. I try to push up my project to Heroku. It done it one time which worked so lost at the moment what the issue can be. when running the command: git push heroku master --force   is not working. I get below errors.

Error LOG:
https://hastebin.com/bofuhaziwa.makefile

Package.JSON file:
https://hastebin.com/pijowuxope.json

Github link:
https://github.com/majkpajk12/veganshop4/tree/9d6712ffea4d3770be540eb46dfaed8643f50f00